# Delete tables in batches (Pyspark)

Tags: pyspark

I have a database that has many tables in it. I want to drop all tables in that database that have "oct" in the name in a batch. Is there a way to do this? I can't find a clear answer online and I don't want to make a mistake and delete tables I shouldn't. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you are talking about `Hive` for simplicity, and the metastore is configured. Then, you can use `spark.sql` to achieve it with the usual SQL commands. List the tables using `like` (with pattern matching), iterate the dataframe and drop them.

```
# Pick all tables in 'agg' schema which contains word 'customer' in it. Usual pattern matching.(In your case, its oct)
df = spark.sql("show tables in agg like '*customer*'")

# Iterate the dataframe that contains list of tables, and drop one by one.
for row in df.rdd.collect():
   print(f'Dropping table {row.tableName}')
   spark.sql(f'drop table agg.{row.tableName}')
```

[image]

Comment: @Jw007, please upvote answer if it worked for you!